# ¿Porque no se eliminan los registros de my db PHP?

Tags: php, html5, mysqli, xampp, mariadb

Hola buenas que tal amigos, tengo un problema con un CRUD que estoy realizando,
el primer crud que realize crea,lee,actualiza,elimina. Pero cuando intento crear otro
CRUD no puedo eliminar los registros de mi db uso la misma db, mismo usuario con todos sus respectivos privilegios,mismo código.

**archivo db_conexion.php**

```
 <?php 
      #FUNCIÓN LLAMADA A CONEXIÓN DB
     function db_query($query) {
     $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "toor", "mydb");
     $consult = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
     mysqli_close($connect);
     return $consult;
     };

    #Funcion de eliminación
     function delete($tabla,$campo_id,$id) {
               //ELIMINA DE LA TABLA X DONDE $campo_id ES IGUAL A ID
        $sql = "DELETE FROM".$tabla."WHERE".$campo_id."=".$id;
        return db_query($sql);
      };

    ?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
  include("db_conexion.php");
?>

<?php
   $x = "SELECT * FROM data";
   $r = db_query($x);
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_object($r) ) {
?>
          <div style="display: flex;">
                <p style="padding-right: 20px;"><?php echo $fila->nombres; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $fila->apellidos; ?></p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="erase.php?id=<?php echo $fila->id_user;?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </div>
          
          


<?php } ; ?>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**erase.php**

```
<?php 
#conexion db
include("db_conexion.php");
?>

<?php 
#el valor de $id
$id = $_GET['id'];
#llama a la funcion a eliminar
delete('data','id_user',$id);
#redirecciona a 
header("location:drop.php");

?>
```

Al momento de querer eliminar un registro pasa la funcion, pero no lo elimina :,v
uso xampp
Soy nuevo en la programación me disculpo de antemano si cometí un error obvio pero no tan obvio para mí. :,v Gracias.

Comment: jajajajajajajajajajaja diablos que soy noob muchas gracias amigo estudiare el tema a fondo no tenia en cuenta los espacios. Muchas gracias capo :v.

Answer (score 1):

El problema estaba en los espacios ya que no los había asignado.

**como estaba antes**

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM".$tabla."WHERE".$campo_id."=".$id;
```

**como debería de ser**

```
$sql = " DELETE FROM ".$tabla." WHERE ".$campo_id."=".$id;
```